# How add 'user_id' in 'ir.values'

Tags: odoo-8

I want to add user_id to model ir.values to give user with id=1 possiblity to view an action

I dont know how that works

```
<record id="value_force_availability" model="ir.values">
     <field name="model_id" ref="stock.model_stock_picking" />
     <field name="name">Force Availability</field>
     <field name="user_id">user</field>
     <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
     <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.act_window,' + 
         str(ref('action_force_availability'))"/>
     <field name="key">action</field>
     <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use field [ref](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/api.py#L796) attribute with a user external id.

Example using `Administrator` user:

```
<field name='user_id' ref='base.user_root'/>
```